# how to run java tcp server in window azure?

Tags: java, azure

how to run java tcp server in window azure?
can window azure do it?

I find so many article about java application for window azure,they is that open a JSP web project in eclipse, and than use worker role publish it in window azure, but my tcp server is general java project, so how to publish it to window azure?

my tcp server:

```java
public class test {

    private static int serverport = 12345;
    private static ServerSocket serverSocket;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(serverport);
            System.out.println("Server is start.");
            while (!serverSocket.isClosed()) {
                System.out.println("Wait new clinet connect!");
                waitNewPlayer();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Server Socket ERROR");
        }
    }


    public static void waitNewPlayer() {
        try {
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();  
            System.out.println(socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress()+"'s socket is connected now!"); 
            createNewUser(socket);
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }


    public static void createNewUser(final Socket socket) {

        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter( new BufferedWriter( new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),true); 

                    out.println("nangnang");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Socket is closed!");
                }   
                System.out.println("This socket is removed form the player array!");
            }
        });
        t.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to run an app like this in Azure, but you'll need to take care of a couple of things:

- Open an *Input Endpoint* for your worker role - this opens the port to the outside world. You then need to either map it to the exact same port internally, or let Azure pick a port for you (and then you can ask the role environment which port you've been assigned, and open that port in your code instead of 12345)
- For all your `println`'s, you'd need to remote-desktop to see them, or you need to push them to diagnostics logging so you can see those debug statements via an external tool like Cerebrata's Diagnostics Manager.

As far as publishing: It's the same as the jsp examples you've seen: you build an Azure project to go along with your Java project, you set up the role size and instance count, create input endpoints, optionally create a cache, set up configuration settings for storage accounts, create a package to run in emulator or in the cloud, etc.

Comment: can you show the process step by step,please!or give me a detail tutorials.
do you export the java project to jar file in eclipse?and put jar file like war file in azure project?

Comment: http://java.interopbridges.com/articles/deploying-a-java-application-to-windows-azure-with-eclipse

i follow this article step by step,i put jre7.zip file and apache-tomcat-7.0.34.zip file in workerrole/approot/JRE and workerrole/approle/tomcat,but i don't know how to do next step,because the next step in article is for jsp,but my java project is not jsp project,i can not export war file,so i don't know how to do next.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to try AzureRunMe which also supports Azure Java Project. http://azurerunme.codeplex.com/